# ODP.Net OracleDependency fails with OS authenticated User

Tags: odp.net

I'm using Oracle Change Notification (OCN) with .NET in my Application for years. But recently my customer wanted to change Database-Login to OS authentication.

This woks fine except for OCN. No notification-events get fired and the OracleDependency object throws an error upon "RemoveRegistration"

I found out that when creating an OracleDependency Object the property "Username" remains empty (normaly it contains the currently connected Username). I think this is because the "User ID" part of the connectionstring contains only "/" in case of OS-authentication. But maybe this is not the reason for the error above.

Any suggestions how to get OCN working with OS authentication?

Thx
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with OS authentication user.

A few seconds after the registration of the Change Notification, it was deregistered again.
We could solve the issue with the following SQL statement:

```
alter system set events '10867 trace name context forever, level 1';
```

Best regards